# How can I render a gridview without ANY style attributes?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Here's my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVWOReport" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsWOReport" 
    onprerender="GVWOReport_PreRender" GridLines="None" CssClass="report" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerRow" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="row" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altRow" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="footer" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's my rendered HTML:

```
<table class="report" cellspacing="0" id="GVWOReport" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

I want the table tag to have nothing but my class and id attributes. I found out that the `GridLines="None"` takes away the border, but I can't get the `cellspacing` and `style` to go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the CellSpacing property to -1 in design view. I don't get any style or cellspacing attributes after doing that. I am using asp.net 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GridView Control Adapter: ASP.NET 2.0 CSS Friendly Control Adapters 1.0](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/gridview.aspx). If offers even more functionality than you need:

> The goal of the adapter for the `GridView` control is to create a
>   `<table>` that is slimmer and better organized than what is produced
>   without the adapter. You could, of course, rewrite this adapter to
>   completely eliminate the `<table>`, replacing it with a variety of `<div>`
>   tags, etc. However, a grid, fundamentally, is a table so it seems
>   logical to leave it as such.
>
> The adapted `GridView` eliminates the use of inline styles. Rows within
>   the `<table>` are organized into `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tbody>` sections.
>   These make it easier to read and understand the markup. More
>   importantly, these sections make it easy to create CSS rules that
>   govern the appearance of particular rows within the `<table>`.

Comment: Use these if you are using asp.net 2.0. If you are using asp.net 4.0, the controls are css friendly for the most part - you just have to set the properties accordingly. If you set Gridlines="None" and CellSpacing="-1", your Gridview will just be a table tag with an ID.